# SPARQL Wikidata - Retrieve members of Wikimedia Category

Tags: sparql, categories, member, wikidata, wikimedia

I want to retrieve the members of the Wikimedia Category `American rock singers`. I **must use Wikidata** and it tells me to use `P31` with `Q4167836` . The query below only returns information about the Category page and not about its members.

Is there any other way to retrieve the members of the Wikimedia Category? I also tried using the term `dcterms:subject`, which I use successfully with DBpedia, but in Wikidata the query returns empty results.

```
prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
prefix wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
prefix wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
prefix bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?predicate ?object ?objectLabel WHERE {
     ?subject ?predicate ?object ; wdt:P31 wd:Q4167836 ; 
     rdfs:label "Category:American rock singers"@en 
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .}
}
```

Try [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#prefix%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0Aprefix%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0Aprefix%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0Aprefix%20bd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%23%3E%0Aprefix%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fobject%20%3FobjectLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%09%3Fsubject%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fobject%20%3B%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ4167836%20%3B%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Category%3AAmerican%20rock%20singers%22%40en%20%0ASERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPARQL - select from skos:category - Virtuoso 37000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765264/sparql-select-from-skoscategory-virtuoso-37000)

Comment: I must use the Wikidata endpoint, not DBpedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query on Wikidata:

```sql
SELECT ?subjectLabel WHERE {
    ?subject wdt:P27 wd:Q30;
             wdt:P136 wd:Q11399 .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .}
}
```

Or try this query on DBpedia (as Mark Miller linked to):

```sql
SELECT str(?label) WHERE {
  ?subject dct:subject dbc:American_rock_singers ;
           rdfs:label ?label .
  FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
}
```

Or if you *must* use Wikidata, try this federated query on Wikidata:

```sql
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
SELECT ?wsubjectLabel WHERE {
    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
         ?subject dct:subject dbc:American_rock_singers .
         ?subject owl:sameAs ?wsubject .
         FILTER (STRSTARTS(STR(?wsubject), "http://www.wikidata.org"))
    }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

Comment: So basically there is no chance to retrieve members from Categories in Wikidata like in DBpedia by using ``dcterms`` or something similar?

Comment: @becom, as far as I know, basically — not. Probably, one can use federated queries.

Comment: Thank you, works for me. Why does Wikidata not support ``dcterms`` though?

Comment: @becorn, _IMHO_, Wikidata has more powerfull facilities for classification and taxonomisation than Wikipedia "categories" and support of these categories is rather a legacy, whereas DBpedia depends on Wikipedia in a greater degree.

Comment: @becorn, and please excuse me for mistypes in your nickname.

Comment: Mistypes are not a big deal for me. Do you have any scientific sources/links for your statement? I am really interested on that part, because it would explain my chosen functions in the documentary on my program.

Comment: No, I have not. But I suppose this statement is a consequense of the fact that DBpedia content is automatically extracted from Dbpedia, while Wikidata content is not.